# Gemfile not found Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've deployed my app to Heroku however, when I try `Heroku run rake db:migrate` or `db:create` I get the message `/Gemfile not found`

All the answers I found searching for the problem relate to local environments but my local environment runs properly; it only happens when I try through Heroku.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Is there more to the Heroku error than `/Gemfile not found`? If so, it *may* help to add the full error to your question.

Comment: If you tried to run `rake db:migrate` it means, that build and deploy on heroku was successful?

Comment: After running the command, terminal output is `Running rake db:migrate` then the error `/Gemfile not found` comes up. And the build does say successful when I push to heroku. I'm also able to view the index pages but I can't navigate to pages that require a db query.

Comment: Are you uploading your gemfile to heroku? and is your gemfile at the root of your app?

Comment: can you also post the screenshot of your error message?

Comment: The gemfile is in the root folder and this is an image of the error https://imgur.com/VBHf14Q

Comment: I also ran find in bash from the heroku app and /Gemfile is listed.

Comment: Did you check in the Gemfile?

Comment: The gemfile is the same as other applications I've pushed to heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had changed the gemfile path in `bin/bundle` from `'../Gemfile', __dir__` to `'/../Gemfile', __FILE__` because of a rubocop offense. I reverted the path back and it resolved the issue.